# Getting errors: "error: conflicting types for ‘call_celsius’ " and "note: previous implicit declaration of ‘call_celsius’ was here"

Tags: c++, c, opengl

i cannot get this code to compile in gcc. ive tried changing the call_celsius to calculate as well as changing it from uppercase to lowercase. im not sure if its because i didnt declare a variable which i dont think is the case, or if i did the call function wrong.

```
/* Homework 1 Question 2 */

/* Purpose: Takes a depth (in kilometers) inside the earth */
/* as input data; Computes and displays the temperature at */
/* depth in degrees Celsius and degrees Fahrenheit.        */

#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

/* Declare Variables */

double depth;
double Celsius;
double Fahrenheit;

/* Obtain Data */

printf("Please enter depth(in kilometers) inside the Earth:  ");
scanf("%lf",&depth);

/* Calculate */

Celsius = call_celsius(depth);
Fahrenheit = call_fahrenheit(Fahrenheit);

/* Output */

printf("The temperature at %lf kilometers is %lf degrees Celsius and %lf degrees       Fahrenheit",depth, Celsius, Fahrenheit);

return 0;
}

double call_celsius(double depth)
{
return((10 * depth) + 20);
}

double call_fahrenheit(double Celsius)

{
return((1.8 * Celsius) + 32);
}
```

these are the errors i receive

```
homework1question2.c:35:8: error: conflicting types for ‘call_celsius’
double call_celsius(double depth)
    ^
homework1question2.c:25:11: note: previous implicit declaration of ‘call_celsius’ was here
Celsius = call_celsius(depth);
       ^
homework1question2.c:40:8: error: conflicting types for ‘call_fahrenheit’
double call_fahrenheit(double Celsius)
    ^
homework1question2.c:26:14: note: previous implicit declaration of ‘call_fahrenheit’ was    here
Fahrenheit = call_fahrenheit(Fahrenheit);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't declare `call_celsius` and `call_fahrenheit`before you used them. Either add function prototypes or declare & define the functions. Here are examples of forward declarations:

```
double call_celsius(double depth);
double call_fahrenheit(double Celsius);
int main(void) {
```

Comment: woot woot! thank you! did not know you needed to declare those variables as well...actually did not know they were their own variables. thank you for the help. compiled and ran smoothly. :)